# Как сделать preloader как на сайте?

Tags: javascript, анимация

Всем привет. Может кто-нибудь подсказать как сделать preloader как на [uix.me](http://uix.me/) с анимацией? Как я понял анимация у них работает через JavaScript, с которым у меня проблемы. Да ещё всё перекомпресировано, не могу найти откуда ноги растут. Вроде перенёс весь HTML и CSS

[codepen](https://codepen.io/sequelone/pen/LQYpVZ)

, а вот что делать с JS не знаю.

```css
.preloader,
.ovly {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 999;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.preloader section,
.ovly section {
    z-index: 1
}

.preloader h3,
.ovly h3 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-family: Sansation-Light;
}
.preloader section {
 width: 100%;
}
.preloader span,
.ovly span {
    display: inline-block
}
.preloader .p1 span:nth-child(1) {
  animation: span-1 1s ease-in-out 1;
}
.preloader .p1 span:nth-child(2) {
  animation: span-2 3s ease-in-out 1;
}
.preloader .p1 span:nth-child(3) {
  animation: span-3 5s ease-in-out 1;
}
.preloader .p1 span:nth-child(4) {
  animation: span-4 7s ease-in-out 1;
}
.preloader .p1 span:nth-child(5) {
  animation: span-5 9s ease-in-out 1;
}
@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
    .preloader span,
    .ovly span {
        display: block;
        margin: 12px 0
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
    .preloader span.dot {
        display: none
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
    .preloader span:nth-child(5):after {
        content: "."
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
    .preloader span:nth-child(6) {
        color: #eb9e66
    }
}

.preloader.active,
.ovly.active {
    display: flex
}

.pline {
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    width: 20%;
    left: 40%;
    bottom: 20%;
    background-color: #bbb;
    -webkit-animation-name: pline; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: pline;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
    .pline {
        width: 50%;
        left: 25%;
        bottom: 10%
    }
}

.pdisc {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    color: #bbb;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 24px
}

.pdisc p {
    font-size: 1rem
}

.pdisc span p {
    -webkit-animation-name: pdisc; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: pdisc;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

.ovly .pdisc {
    bottom: 25%
}

@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
    .ovly .pdisc {
        bottom: 24px
    }
}

.ovly .pdisc p {
    font-size: 1.25rem
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes span-1 {
  25% {transform: matrix(0.99619, 0.08715, 0.08715, 0.99619, 0, 60);opacity: 1;}
  50% {transform: matrix(0.99619, 0.08715, 0.08715, 0.99619, 0, 60);opacity: 0.2;}
  100% {transform: matrix(0.99619, 0.08715, 0.08715, 0.99619, 0, 60);opacity: 0;display: none;}
  to {display: none;}
}
@keyframes span-2 {
  25% {transform: matrix(0.99619, 0.08715, 0.08715, 0.99619, 0, 60);opacity: 1;}
  50% {transform: matrix(0.99619, 0.08715, 0.08715, 0.99619, 0, 60);opacity: 0.2;}
  100% {transform: matrix(0.99619, 0.08715, 0.08715, 0.99619, 0, 60);opacity: 0;display: none;}
  to {display: none;}
}
@keyframes span-3 {
  25% {transform: matrix(0.99619, 0.08715, 0.08715, 0.99619, 0, 60);opacity: 1;}
  50% {transform: matrix(0.99619, 0.08715, 0.08715, 0.99619, 0, 60);opacity: 0.2;}
  100% {transform: matrix(0.99619, 0.08715, 0.08715, 0.99619, 0, 60);opacity: 0;display: none;}
  to {display: none;}
}
@keyframes span-4 {
  0% {transform: matrix(0.99619, 0.08715, 0.08715, 0.99619, 0, 60);opacity: 1;}
  50% {transform: matrix(0.99619, 0.08715, 0.08715, 0.99619, 0, 60);opacity: 0.2;}
  100% {transform: matrix(0.99619, 0.08715, 0.08715, 0.99619, 0, 60);opacity: 0;display: none;}
  to {display: none;}
}
@keyframes span-5 {
  25% {transform: matrix(0.99619, 0.08715, 0.08715, 0.99619, 0, 60);opacity: 1;}
  50% {transform: matrix(0.99619, 0.08715, 0.08715, 0.99619, 0, 60);opacity: 0.2;}
  100% {transform: matrix(0.99619, 0.08715, 0.08715, 0.99619, 0, 60);opacity: 0;display: none;}
  to {display: none;}
}
@keyframes pdisc {
    100% {transform: matrix(0.99619, 0.08715, 0.08715, 0.99619, 0, 60)}
}

@keyframes pline {
  0% {width: 20%}
  100% {width: 0%}
}
```

```html
<div class="preloader active">
 <section>
  <h3 class="p1">
  <span>Just</span>
  <span>doing</span>
  <span>what</span>
  <span>I</span>
  <span>love</span>
  </h3>
  <div class="pline"></div>
  <div class="pdisc"><span><p>Diese Seite nutzt Cookies. Willkommen im Jahr 2018.</p></div>
 </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот `preloader` написанный мной на [codepen](https://codepen.io/kadirinan/pen/jazKmQ)

Он использует GSAP в качестве анимационного движка.
Это только JS который вам нужен:

```
var tlpl = new TimelineMax(),
$p1 = $('.p1 span');

tlpl.staggerTo($p1, 0.5,{
    opacity: 0,
    y: '-30',
    skewX: '5deg',
    skewY: '5deg',

},0.10,'+=1.65');
```